# Cloud Run connect to Cloud SQL module error Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I keep getting an error trying to connect Cloud Run and I keep getting the following error. Any idea?

```
 __import__("pg8000") ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pg8000'
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import datetime
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import warnings
from flask import Flask
import os
import google
db_user = os.environ.get("DB_USER")
db_pass = os.environ.get("DB_PASS")
db_name = os.environ.get("DB_NAME")
cloud_sql_connection_name = os.environ.get("CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME")

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    # Equivalent URL:
    # postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_sock=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername='postgres+psycopg2',
        username=db_user,
        password=db_pass,
        database=db_name,
        query={
            'unix_sock': '/cloudsql/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432'.format(
                cloud_sql_connection_name)
        }
    ),
    # ... Specify additional properties here.
    # ...
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install one of the [supported database drivers](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html).

If you want to use `postgres+pg8000`, you need to install the [`pg8000`](http://pypi.org/p/pg8000) package, otherwise based on your example, you actually need to install [`psycopg2`](https://pypi.org/p/psycopg2/).

Comment: Do I need to replace the credentials with my own for the database instance or is likely to be found when I run gcloud deploy? Thanks Dustin

Comment: You'll need to set those environment variables with the credentials specific to the instance you're connecting to. Cloud Run doesn't know anything about the DB you want to connect to.